# Where is mongo database folder on the filesystem

Tags: 16.04, files, filesystem, database, mongodb

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. I have set up a database `MongoDB`. When I start it (with `mongod` command) it says that database is located at `/data/db` (`dbpath=/data/db`).

The database works fine. But in files explorer I cannot find that folder. I've looked in `Computer` folder and in `Home` (`Computer/home/<my name>`) folder.

I also showed hidden files and folders with Ctrl+H.

How can I find my database folder?

Answer (score 57):

You should be able to find the location in the configuration file: `/etc/mongod.conf`

```
grep -i dbPath /etc/mongod.conf
```

---

According to [mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/):

The default path is `/data/db` directory

> By default, MongoDB listens for connections from clients on port
>   27017, and stores data in the /data/db directory.

If `dbPath` is set, the mongodb will use the directory specify by `dbPath`

> If you want `mongod` to store data files at a path other than `/data/db`
>   you can specify a `dbPath`. The `dbPath` must exist before you start
>   `mongod`. If it does not exist, create the directory and the permissions
>   so that `mongod` can read and write data to this path. For more
>   information on permissions, see the security operations documentation.

Comment: I found /etc/mongod.conf (notice there is no 'b' letter). There it says: storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb. And that folder looks like it could be the database. Also the variable is dbPath (uppercase 'P'). But then why the hell when I start mongod it says dbpath=/data/db?

Comment: @croraf - the `/data/db` is the default value of the path, if `dbPath` is set, it override this value. Note that in order to use `/data/db` as actual path,  the folder should be exists and have the correct ownership/permissions. see updated answer with link to mongodb docs

Comment: Thanks! The issue is mongod command outputs "MongoDB starting : pid=2722 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=korisnik-Lenovo-Y520-15IKBN" indicating that dbpath is /data/db. Although this could be the default path the db starting command should indicate the actual path, in my case /var/lib/mongodb.

Comment: @croraf `/etc/mongod.conf` configuration is only used if you [Start MongoDB as a service](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#start-mongodb) or explicitly pass this on the command line: `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`. If you start `mongod` without any options the default of `/data/db` will be used. If you start `mongod` as a service on Ubuntu, `dbPath` will be as specified in `/etc/mongod.conf` (`/var/lib/mongodb` by default). Typically you want to be managing MongoDB as a service to ensure consistent configuration is used between invocations.

Comment: @Stennie Yes it seems mongod is started on OS boot (what you call 'as a service'). This was confusing me. I will check today but probably running mongod gives error that the port is already bound.

Answer (score 9):

When using linux (Ubuntu), when you install mongodb, it is automatically configured and run by default. The default dbpath is located in `mongodb.conf`. You should see the following lines:

```
   # Where to store the data
   dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb
```

Now, based on [mongodb doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/):

> The default path is[should be] `/data/db` directory, but if the folder
>   isn't present, mongodb will fire from the path given in the
>   mongodb.conf file.

What to do:

1. stop your mongodb.
2. create your default data folder.
3. restart mongodb: this time it will start from the data folder you created.

Answer (score 1):

I) From MongoDB Configuration file we can find it out.
dbPath is mentioned in it.

II) From mongo shell execute the following to find dbPath location
db.adminCommand({getCmdLineOpts:1}).parsed.storage.dbPath

Answer (score 0):

Try typing `file:///data/db/` in the browser (chrome or fire-fox). You'll be able to see the files and collections if you have `mongodb` installed in system, but all would be encrypted you cannot read them in an editor.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the "root" that you are seeing, is not the real root, its the root of your home, on the File explorer, when you are on your 'root' home page, press `backspace` to go to the parent folder.